# Why do you need primers in PCR?

Tags: dna, pcr, dna-replication, primer, polymerase

I have read that DNA polymerase requires a primer to bind to the DNA, but I am confused as to why this is the case. When DNA undergoes replication in the cell, there are no primers in the nucleus. Why are they needed in PCR?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Who said that there are no primers in the nucleus? Read about Primase. I advise that you pick up a good book on basic molecular biology and read the chapter on replication. Genes by Lewin is a decent book.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thank you for your reply. I see now that there is RNA primase in the nucleus- this makes more sense! However i'm now confused as to why an RNA strand is synthesised? I understand that RNA polymerase works on only one strand and DNA polymerase works on two, however does it not make a difference to the finished product that the ends of the DNA strands are actually RNA?

Comment: There is a question about this here. DNA polymerase cannot synthesize without primers but RNA polymerase can. Primase is a kind of RNA polymerase.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when DNA replicate in cell, there is primer exists. DNA polymerase only can **add deoxyribonucleotide (dNTP) to the 3’end** of a growing DNA chain, instead of creating a new strand. Here is the picture for DNA replication in legging strand, but is same principal use in leading strand. Primer is synthesized by primase in replication.

[image]

It is also worth to mention that, looking at the last step, there is a primer there and must be removed, and DNA maybe shorter in each DNA replication time, and that is why DNA telomere mechanism is proposed. That may be a key point for aging.

So, in PCR, it also needs primers, for DNA polymerase only can only can **add dNTP to the 3’end** of a growing DNA chain.